# Count all rows from a colum, and get 2 different count columns on the result (One for each possible value 1 or 0)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, count

Thank you for taking your time to read my question.

What I want to do is to count all rows from a colum (State), and get 2 different count columns on the result (One for each possible value 1 or 0).

For example I have this table (Called “product”) with these rows:

```
  ProductID |Subcategory| State |
    101     |   201     |   1   |
    102     |   201     |   1   |
    103     |   201     |   1   |
    104     |   202     |   0   |
    105     |   202     |   0   |
    106     |   203     |   1   |
    107     |   203     |   0   |
    108     |   203     |   0   |
```

State: 1=Active, 0=Inactive

So I want to get this:

```
|Subcategory| Active|Inactive|
|   201     |   3   |   0    |
|   202     |   0   |   2    |
|   202     |   1   |   2    |
```

Do you know how can I do this?

I was trying with this query and inserting the results in a temptable:

```
SELECT product.Subcategory, 
COUNT(product.Subcategory) AS Products
FROM product,subcategory,category
WHERE product.Subcategory = subcategory.SubcategoryId
AND product.State = 1 or 0
AND subcategory.Category = category.CategoryId
GROUP BY product.Subcategory
```

But I get just the products with State = 1 or 0

I tried LEFT JOIN but I couldn’t get what I need it.

This is what I’m trying… (But it is not working)

```
SELECT P.Subcategory, 
        COUNT(P.State)
FROM product AS P
LEFT JOIN(
SELECT product.Subcategory AS S, 
        COUNT(product.State) AS C
FROM product
WHERE product.State = 0
GROUP BY product.Subcategory) AS t
ON t.S = p.Subcategory
```

I swear I checked on other user questions like:

[Display zero by using count(*) if no result returned for a particular case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965658/display-zero-by-using-count-if-no-result-returned-for-a-particular-case)

[SQL - Returning all rows even if count is zero for item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747855/sql-returning-all-rows-even-if-count-is-zero-for-item)

But I couldn’t find what I need it.

Could you please help me with this? =)

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select p.subcategory,
       sum(case when state = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as active,
       sum(case when state = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as inactive
from product p
group by p.subcategory
```

Comment: Boom! Fastest answer ever! Thanks so much! I just spent hours and hours on this... Thanks God we have peaple like you! :) @GordonLinoff

Comment: Else condition may be avoided here also                                                                        sum(case when state = 1 then 1 end) as active

Comment: @BharatBhushanSharma . . . Removing the `else` runs the risk of returning `NULL`.

Comment: it can be managed using isnull() like                                                           
sum(case when isnull(state,0) = 1 then 1 end)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in two ways.

One is by using `Conditional Aggregate` use `Count` Instead of `Sum` to avoid `Else` part in `case statement`

```
SELECT subcategory,
       Count(CASE WHEN state = 1 THEN 1 END) AS Active,
       Count(CASE WHEN state = 0 THEN 1 END) AS InActive
FROM   product 
GROUP  BY subcategory
```

Another way is by using `Pivot`

```
SELECT subcategory,
       [1] AS Active,
       [0] AS InActive
FROM   (SELECT subcategory,
               State,
               ProductID
        FROM   product) a
       PIVOT(Count(ProductID)
            FOR State IN([1],[0])) piv
```

Comment: Thanks man! I didnt know PIVOT exists... Thanks a lot! @NoDisplayName

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SELECT subcategory,
         Count(State) AS TotalC,
         ABS(Sum(State)) AS Active,
         TotalC-Active AS InActive
FROM product GROUP BY ProductID;
```

Comment: why did you add your email? The system found your answer as spam.